# check all data from object javascript

Tags: javascript

hi guys I have an object like this

```js
const tmp ={
    identityType:null,
    identityNumber:null,
    nationality:null,
    firstName:null,
    secondName:null,
    gender:null,
    birthDate:null,
    bornCountry:null,
    profession:null,
    province:null,
    city:null,
    address:null,
    postCode:null,
    img:null,
  };
```

can I check the tmp if all data is not null I will do something ?, I know the easy way just use if , but the data is too much if I'm using If operator ?

Comment: Use `Object.values()` and `some()` or `every()`

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+check+if+all+object+values+are+non-null) of [Determining if all attributes on a javascript object are null or an empty string](/q/27709636/4642212). Just adapt the conditions of the existing answers, e.g. `Object.values(tmp).every((value) => value !== null)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `every()` method to test if all elements of an array fit some criteria. And `Object.values()` to get the values in the object as an array.

```
if (Object.values(tmp).every(el => el !== null)) {
    console.log("All values are not null");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if all values are nulls just check if

```
Object.values(tmp).filter(el => el !== null).length === 0
```

The same for all falsey values (null, undefined, 0, etc.)

```
Object.values(tmp).filter(el => Boolean(el)).length === 0
```

Comment: `every` is better than `filter` for this. It doesn't create a new array, and stops as soon as it knows the answer.

Comment: @Barmar, yes indeed, you're right, I simply forgot about `every`. Post your answer and I'll upvote it!